# Can't manage to remove event listeners from element

Tags: javascript

I have to functions which are being called in different places. The first one initializes event listeners and `destroy()` tries to remove those event listeners. The initialization is working, the destruction not.

```
private onClick = (index) => {
    // do something with index
}

load = (data) => {
    this.initialPositions = data;

    this.initialPositions.forEach((value, index) => {
        value.frame.addEventListener("click", this.onClick.bind(value.frame, index));
    });
};

destroy = () => {
    this.initialPositions.forEach((value, index) => {
        value.frame.removeEventListener("click", this.onClick.bind(value.frame, index));
    });
};
```

`initialPosition` is an array of objects including `frame` which is a DOM Element and supposed to listen for click events.

Within the application, if already initialized, `destroy` is being called before `load` to remove the event listeners of the previously set `initialPositions`. This seems to not work, since repeating this process, `onClick` will be executed multiple times.

Comment: Hi, It looks like the addEventListener and removeEventListener does not have properly closed paranthesis.

Comment: `removeEventListener` requires the reference to the exact same function object, that was used in `addEventListener`. With `bind`, you are creating a _new_ function each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.onClick.bind()` is creating a *new function object*, which means you are calling `removeEventListener()` with a different function that you called `addEventListener` with. What you'll need to do is push the reference to each onClick handler to an array when you call `load()` and then iterate the array, passing each element to `removeEventListener` when you destroy. Something like this:

```
load = (data) => {
    this.initialPositions = data;
    this.bindings = []
    this.initialPositions.forEach((value, index) => {
        const binding = this.onClick.bind(value.frame, index)
        this.bindings.push(binding)
        value.frame.addEventListener("click", binding);
    });
};

destroy = () => {
    this.bindings.forEach((binding) => {
        value.frame.removeEventListener("click", binding);
    });
    delete this.bindings;
};
```

Comment: Thanks! Did you put `this.boundOnClick = this.onClick.bind(value.frame, index);` outside of the `forEach` loop on purpose? Since value and index aren't available outside, right?

Comment: Oh. That's a mistake on my part. It makes things slightly more complicated. You'll need to push to an array and probably use the array to call the listeners.